# 'Selectable' alternative to an optgroup in a select pulldown?

Tags: html, css, select, mobile

Using the `optgroup` tag with in a `select` you can create a list of subheadings for your items:

```
subhead
    option 1
    option 2
subhead 2
    option 3
    option 4
```

Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup

Is there anything like this, be it HTML, JS or CSS that would allow the same formatting, but allowing the subheads to also be selectable options?

The catch is that we'd still like this usable as a default UI widget on a mobile device. While it's easy enough to format a custom drop down menu that would allow this with some jQuery on the desktop browser side, we'd really prefer it to be a native HTML control on the mobile side of things to leverage the native UI for `select`. Does there exist a way to format a native `select` so that you can have visually outdented subjeads that are selectable?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, default HTML does not have such a construct.